# Spark Filter data with groupby count

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

A dataframe A_df like:

```
+------+----+-----+
|   uid|year|month|
+------+----+-----+
|     1|2017|   03|
      1|2017|   05|
|     2|2017|   01|
|     3|2017|   02|
|     3|2017|   04|
|     3|2017|   05|
+------+----+-----+
```

I want filter column uid with occurrence time more than 2 times,
Expected result:

```
+------+----+-----+
|   uid|year|month|
+------+----+-----+
|     3|2017|   02|
|     3|2017|   04|
|     3|2017|   05|
+------+----+-----+
```

How can I get this result by Scala?
My solution:

```scala
val condition_uid = A_df.groupBy("uid")
                  .agg(count("*").alias("cnt"))
                  .filter("cnt > 2").select("uid")
val results_df = A_df.join(condition_uid, Seq("uid"))
```

Is there better answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think using window function is the perfect solution since you do not have to rejoin the dataframe.

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy("year")

df.withColumn("count", count("uid").over(window))
  .filter($"count" > 2).drop("count").show
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-----+-----+
|uid|year|month|count|
+---+----+-----+-----+
|  1|2017|   03|    2|
|  1|2017|   05|    2|
|  2|2017|   01|    1|
+---+----+-----+-----+
```